# update_forward_refs() fails for dynamically-created model

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

When I create a pydantic model dynamically via `create_model()` then in some situations `update_forward_refs()` can't find the relevant definition.

This works:

```
from typing import List, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Foo(BaseModel):
    foo: List["Bar"]

Bar = Union[Foo, int]
Foo.update_forward_refs()
```

But the following, which I believe should be equivalent, fails with a NameError:

```
from typing import List, Union
from pydantic import create_model, BaseModel
Foo = create_model("Foo", foo=(List["Bar"], ...))
Bar = Union[Foo, int]
Foo.update_forward_refs()
```

resulting in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_forward_ref.py", line 11, in <module>
    Foo.update_forward_refs()
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 832, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.update_forward_refs
  File "pydantic\typing.py", line 382, in pydantic.typing.update_field_forward_refs
    or class checks.
  File "pydantic\typing.py", line 62, in pydantic.typing.evaluate_forwardref
    'MutableSet',
  File "C:\Users\Ian\.conda\envs\tso\lib\typing.py", line 518, in _evaluate
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined
```

It is significant that "Bar" is refered to within a List in the annotation for field `foo`. If the annotation of field `foo` is directly "Bar" then there is no problem.

Can someone please me towards fixing this please? What else do I need to do?

Python 3.8 and pydantic 1.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`update_forward_refs()`](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/f529e0d3541d3cab0aa9c2795a747cd8af4968e5/pydantic/main.py#L786) admits a `**localns: Any` parameter. It seems that in this case you can pass `Bar=Bar` to `update_forward_refs()` and it will work:

```python
from typing import List, Union

from pydantic import create_model

Foo = create_model("Foo", foo=(List["Bar"], ...))
Bar = Union[Foo, int]
Foo.update_forward_refs(Bar=Bar)

print(Foo(foo=[1, Foo(foo=[2])]))
```

Output:

```
foo=[1, Foo(foo=[2])]
```